# Don't display HTML code and entities in dropdownlists

Tags: asp.net

When I add &nbsp; or &eacute; to a text value of a listitem, it display the code of the HTML entity instead of the result (a space or é).

I can add "physical" non-breaking spaces or special chars, but I would like to avoid that if possible. Sometimes the data stored in database is encoded, and I don't want to always process data before displaying it.

Any solution ?

Thanks

Edit note : previous description noted it was about a dropdownlist simulating a treeview, but it was merely an example ; I can't and don't want to replace the dropdownlist by anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ListItems are automatically HtmlEncoded.

You can HtmlDecode the list items before hand, so when they are HtmlEncoded you get the proper characters:

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = new List<string> { Server.HtmlDecode("A&hellip;"), Server.HtmlDecode("B&nbsp;C") };
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`<optgroup>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) tag for hierarchical (i.e., tree-like) drop-down menus.

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Parent 1">
        <option>Child 1.1</option>
        <option>Child 1.2</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Parent 2">
        <option>Child 2.1</option>
        <option>Child 2.2</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard drop down lists are very poor at representing treeviews .

They can handle going one level deep if the top level is not selectable (see the [optgroup](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTGROUP) element[1]), but beyond that I suggest taking a regular list (ordered or unordered) with as much nesting as you need (remember sublists go inside list items in their parent list) and including a checkbox or radio button with each selectable list item.

Some JavaScript could then be added to manipulate classes to create a drop down effect if desired.

[1] Optgroup should be able to go deeper but, IIRC, browser support is sucky.

Answer (score 0):

Try with ul(ol) and play with the css. You can use jquery to change style if some requirements are met (li has value attribute)

Answer (score 0):

The problem described in the question isn't what I see using a current version of ASP.NET -- when I try it, both the following `&ndash;` are rendered correctly:

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="Visibility" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="public" Text="Public &ndash; All users"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="private">Private &ndash; Only you</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```